# D3, Multidimensional data and enter()

Tags: d3.js

I am an R user who is new to JS and D3, and I am struggling with examples more elaborate than single plots with  1+ lines.  I have a nested data structure (below) and want to map the data into each panel based onto the first layer, and each data series by the second layer.  However, .enter() appears to hit the first layer, and only draw that many points.

[A mockup of what I want, in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zqm3.jpg).  Is there an example to follow regarding multiple plots, lines and nested data inputs?  What should I be doing here?

My current failing attempt following the example from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563) for margin conventions:

```
  var data = [{"A": [{"y": 1, "x": 360}, {"y": 2, "x": 541}, {"y": 3, "x": 634}, {"y": 4, "x": 818}, {"y": 5, "x": 879}, {"y": 6, "x": 1014}, {"y": 7, "x": 1136}, {"y": 8, "x": 1237}, {"y": 9, "x": 1415}, {"y": 10, "x": 1594}, {"y": 11, "x": 1594}], "B": [{"y": 1, "x": 401}, {"y": 2, "x": 541}, {"y": 3, "x": 613}, {"y": 4, "x": 679}, {"y": 5, "x": 741}, {"y": 6, "x": 914}, {"y": 7, "x": 1189}, {"y": 8, "x": 1312}, {"y": 9, "x": 1577}, {"y": 10, "x": 1635}, {"y": 11, "x": 1664}, {"y": 12, "x": 1725}, {"y": 13, "x": 1854}, {"y": 14, "x": 1885}], "C": [{"y": 1, "x": 414}, {"y": 2, "x": 539}, {"y": 3, "x": 696}, {"y": 4, "x": 815}, {"y": 5, "x": 926}, {"y": 6, "x": 1204}, {"y": 7, "x": 1234}, {"y": 8, "x": 1368}, {"y": 9, "x": 1638}, {"y": 10, "x": 1671}, {"y": 11, "x": 1708}], "D": [{"y": 1, "x": 362}, {"y": 2, "x": 492}, {"y": 3, "x": 539}, {"y": 4, "x": 584}, {"y": 5, "x": 651}, {"y": 6, "x": 730}, {"y": 7, "x": 812}, {"y": 8, "x": 990}, {"y": 9, "x": 1190}, {"y": 10, "x": 1366}, {"y": 11, "x": 1523}, {"y": 12, "x": 1853}, {"y": 13, "x": 1853}], "E": [{"y": 1, "x": 372}, {"y": 2, "x": 544}, {"y": 3, "x": 631}, {"y": 4, "x": 716}, {"y": 5, "x": 807}, {"y": 6, "x": 922}, {"y": 7, "x": 1145}, {"y": 8, "x": 1147}, {"y": 9, "x": 1373}, {"y": 10, "x": 1568}, {"y": 11, "x": 1642}, {"y": 12, "x": 1782}, {"y": 13, "x": 1847}, {"y": 14, "x": 1848}]}, {"F": [{"y": 1, "x": 362}, {"y": 2, "x": 524}, {"y": 3, "x": 597}, {"y": 4, "x": 661}, {"y": 5, "x": 725}, {"y": 6, "x": 862}, {"y": 7, "x": 948}, {"y": 8, "x": 982}, {"y": 9, "x": 1130}, {"y": 10, "x": 1225}, {"y": 11, "x": 1411}, {"y": 12, "x": 1633}, {"y": 13, "x": 1804}, {"y": 14, "x": 1851}], "G": [{"y": 1, "x": 429}, {"y": 2, "x": 544}, {"y": 3, "x": 610}, {"y": 4, "x": 702}, {"y": 5, "x": 808}, {"y": 6, "x": 931}, {"y": 7, "x": 1202}, {"y": 8, "x": 1339}, {"y": 9, "x": 1401}, {"y": 10, "x": 1487}, {"y": 11, "x": 1490}, {"y": 12, "x": 1807}, {"y": 13, "x": 1845}], "H": [{"y": 1, "x": 366}, {"y": 2, "x": 542}, {"y": 3, "x": 593}, {"y": 4, "x": 661}, {"y": 5, "x": 842}, {"y": 6, "x": 845}, {"y": 7, "x": 930}, {"y": 8, "x": 978}, {"y": 9, "x": 1088}, {"y": 10, "x": 1304}, {"y": 11, "x": 1336}, {"y": 12, "x": 1485}, {"y": 13, "x": 1538}, {"y": 14, "x": 1587}, {"y": 15, "x": 1588}, {"y": 16, "x": 1691}, {"y": 17, "x": 1740}, {"y": 18, "x": 1741}, {"y": 19, "x": 1742}, {"y": 20, "x": 1783}, {"y": 21, "x": 1863}], "I": [{"y": 1, "x": 418}, {"y": 2, "x": 518}, {"y": 3, "x": 596}, {"y": 4, "x": 664}, {"y": 5, "x": 858}, {"y": 6, "x": 927}, {"y": 7, "x": 972}, {"y": 8, "x": 1028}, {"y": 9, "x": 1125}, {"y": 10, "x": 1397}, {"y": 11, "x": 1401}, {"y": 12, "x": 1737}, {"y": 13, "x": 1835}, {"y": 14, "x": 1915}], "J": [{"y": 1, "x": 367}, {"y": 2, "x": 498}, {"y": 3, "x": 555}, {"y": 4, "x": 622}, {"y": 5, "x": 680}, {"y": 6, "x": 792}, {"y": 7, "x": 872}, {"y": 8, "x": 931}, {"y": 9, "x": 1069}, {"y": 10, "x": 1141}, {"y": 11, "x": 1232}, {"y": 12, "x": 1396}, {"y": 13, "x": 1485}, {"y": 14, "x": 1561}, {"y": 15, "x": 1624}, {"y": 16, "x": 1777}, {"y": 17, "x": 1841}, {"y": 18, "x": 1841}]}]
params = {"x_min": 360, "y_max": 21, "y_min": 1, "x_max": 1915};



var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    padding = {top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 60, left: 60},
    outerWidth = 500,
    outerHeight = 500,
    innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = innerWidth - padding.left - padding.right,
    height = innerHeight - padding.top - padding.bottom;

var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('basis')
    .x(function(d){return x(d.x_var)})
    .y(function(d){return y(d.y_var)});



// Insert an svg:svg element (with margin) for each row in our dataset. A
// child svg:g element translates the origin to the pie center.
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([params['x_min'],params['x_max']]).range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([params['y_min'], params['y_max']]).range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");


var g = svg.append("g")

    .attr("width", outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);
g.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("cx",  function(d){return x(500)} )
        .attr("cy", function(d){return y(5)})
        .attr("r", 4)
```

Comment: You'll need a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for this. By the looks of it, three levels of nesting -- figures at the top level, groups of lines at the second and individual lines at the bottom.

Comment: Subselections, good data structuring with nest(), and finally wrapping my head around the reverse data bind did the job.

Comment: Great, would you mind posting what you did as an answer for reference?

Comment: Made it so, Lars.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, and added some bells and whistles.  (Mouseover points for tooltips, mouseover color blocks in legend to fade out the other series, click points for URLs.)

Key things to note in the conversion: the data set is just an array of objects, which gets restructured by nest() into a friendlier form.  This forces some rewriting of the data access calls later.

```
function convertToSlug(Text)
{
    return Text
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g,'-')
        .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')
        ;
}

var getVals = function(obj){
   var vals = [];
   for(var key in obj){
      vals.push(obj[key]);
   }
   return vals;
}

var data_structure = {"data": [{"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 12}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 13}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 17}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 18}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 20}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 21}, {"y_var": 9, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 23}, {"y_var": 10, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 11, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 1", "group_var": "Group 1", "x_var": 26}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 12}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 19}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 24}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 2", "group_var": "Group 2", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 12}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 17}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 17}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 19}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 20}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 21}, {"y_var": 9, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 24}, {"y_var": 10, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 11, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 3", "group_var": "Group 3", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 11}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 20}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 24}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 4", "group_var": "Group 4", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 11}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 17}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 19}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 21}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 23}, {"y_var": 9, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 10, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 11, "split_var": "Split 1", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 5", "group_var": "Group 5", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 12}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 17}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 18}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 20}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 21}, {"y_var": 9, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 10, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 6", "group_var": "Group 6", "x_var": 28}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 11}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 19}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 22}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 26}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 29}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 7", "group_var": "Group 7", "x_var": 29}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 11}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 17}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 20}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 24}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 8", "group_var": "Group 8", "x_var": 29}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 13}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 19}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 21}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 25}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 27}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 29}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 9", "group_var": "Group 9", "x_var": 29}, {"y_var": 1, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 12}, {"y_var": 2, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 14}, {"y_var": 3, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 15}, {"y_var": 4, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 16}, {"y_var": 5, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 18}, {"y_var": 6, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 19}, {"y_var": 7, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 21}, {"y_var": 8, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 24}, {"y_var": 9, "split_var": "Split 2", "tooltip": "Point Tooltip", "label": "Group 10", "group_var": "Group 10", "x_var": 27}], "parameters": {"y_min": 1, "x_label": "Time (m)", "y_label": "Level", "y_max": 11, "x_max": 29, "draw_path": true, "x_min": 11}}

raw_data = data_structure['data']
params = data_structure['parameters']
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    padding = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
    outerWidth = 400,
    outerHeight = 400,
    innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = innerWidth - padding.left - padding.right,
    height = innerHeight - padding.top - padding.bottom;
data = d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.split_var;}).key(function(d){return d.group_var;}).entries(raw_data);

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);


var svg = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x_var); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y_var); });


var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([params['x_min'],params['x_max']]).range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([params['y_min'], params['y_max']]).range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("y", -16)
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(params['x_label']);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(params['y_label']);

g.append("g")
.attr('class','title')
.attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
.append("text")
  .attr("x", width/2*1.2)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d){return d.key;});

var series = g.selectAll('.series').data(function(d){
        return(d.values);
    }).enter().append('g')
.attr("class", 'dataset')
.attr("id", function(d){return convertToSlug(d.key);});

series.selectAll('.points').data(function(d){return d.values;}).enter()
    .append("a").attr("xlink:href", function(d) {if(d.url){return d.url;} else {return '';}})
.append('circle')
.attr('cx',function(d){return(x(d.x_var)); })
.attr('cy',function(d){return(y(d.y_var)); })
.attr('r', 5)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(String(d.label));})
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
        div .html(d.tooltip)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    });

if(params['draw_path']){
  series.append("svg:path").attr("d", function(d){return(line(d.values));})
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.values[0].label);})
  .style("stroke-width", 3)
  .style("fill", 'none');
}
var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("width", 100)
.attr("transform", "translate(10,20)");

var rows = legend.selectAll('rect')
      .data(function(d){return d.values;})
      .enter();
    rows.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 50)
      .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
         var return_color = color(d.values[0].label);
         return return_color;
      })
      .on("mouseover",
        function (d, i) {
          d3.selectAll('.dataset').filter(function(p){return convertToSlug(p.key)!=convertToSlug(d.key);})
          .transition().duration(1000).style('opacity',0.2);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.selectAll('.dataset').filter(function(p){return convertToSlug(p.key)!=convertToSlug(d.key);})
            .transition().duration(1000).style('opacity',1);
    });

    rows.append('text')
      .attr("x", 62)
      .attr("y", function(d, i){ return 11+(i *  20);})
      .text(function(d){return d.key;});
```